# Why can't Google Maps API access custom CSS file from JS in HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML with JS

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/custom.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
        <div id="map">
            <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCQKR41AqiPXn-2WfLS-ksdsad&callback=initMap"></script>

        <script>
          function initMap() {
              var uluru = { lat: 51.957244, lng: 4.570751 };
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                  zoom: 15,
                  center: uluru
              });
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: uluru,
                  map: map
              });
          }
        </script>
</div>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

The specific problem is that when I put  CSS in the HTML with #map the map shows and works but from the separate file it just doesn't show. Why?

EDIT: Making a MVC application via Visual Studio

EDIT 2: Something with the file location was wrong. I created a new project and put the CSS in a file that was already made. Now it's working.

Comment: Is `~` actually a folder in the root of your project, or are you expecting the browser to understand and expand it to the home folder?

Comment: I expect it to expand it

Comment: Not a fix but the `<link>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first - put your script tags into head and try again. I suspect that there's some funky stuff with google maps replacing contents of #map and removing scripts in the process.

Comment: Have you used browser console to verify that external CSS is actually loading?

Comment: How do i do that my friend?

Comment: With google chrome, hit F12. You want to check console tab, and then network tab to see what resources are loaded.

Comment: Yes It is loading I can see the CSS file in the resources

Answer (score 0):

It should be `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/custom.css" />` Use `.` insteads of `~`

Comment: The `<link>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. It works fine here. It looks like wrong location for css file.